# Angular Material Change Detection using ngOnChanges throwing error, "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular6, angular-changedetection

I have a Input property for a component and I should only display if the current data is not undefined.

I'm using ngOnChanges to detect the changes, but it's throwing "**ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError**" error.

Here's the code,

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
if (changes['message'].currentValue) {
  this.open();
}}


open() {
    let config = new MatSnackBarConfig();
    config.verticalPosition = this.verticalPosition;
    config.horizontalPosition = this.horizontalPosition;
    config.duration = this.setAutoHide ? this.autoHide : 0;
    config.extraClasses = this.addExtraClass ? ['test'] : undefined;
    this.snackBar.open(this.message, this.action ? this.actionButtonLabel : undefined, config);
}
```

Stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snackbar-top-bdmsmz

Is there any way to resolve the error.

[image: Stackblitz error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error goes way in this way:

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: { [propName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
      if (changes['message'].currentValue) {
          this.open();
        }
        })
      }
```

Comment: just replace the ngOnChanges code of your through this code.

Comment: I don't think it is a standardised solution for this problem. Anyone has any other solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is problem related to the lifecycle events of Angular.

One quick way to fix it is to wrap the misbehaving code, which in this case is the `snackBar.open` call, in a `setTimeout` function

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.snackBar.open(this.message, this.action ? this.actionButtonLabel : undefined, config);
})
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snackbar-top-ydvzhk?file=app/hello.component.ts)